# CardAction button with type=call doesn't work

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger

I am creating a bot using MS bot framework and I can't create a button that would call a phone number. This should be possible according to this - http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html - search under "action types" (call).

This is the code that is supposed to create a button in a HeroCard / ThumbnailCard, but it doesn't work. The whole card doesn't show up in the reply. If I comment out that code, the HeroCard / ThumbnailCard shows up normally. (I have another button with the type openUrl which works fine).

In the code below, button1 doesn't work while button2 appears normally if I comment out the code for button1.

UPDATE: it turns out the code works fine when I'm talking to the bot through Telegram, but doesn't work when I'm talking to the bot through Facebook Messenger.

```
    List<CardAction> buttons = new List<CardAction>();
        CardAction button1 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "tel:123123123123",
            Type = "Call",
            Title = "Call us"
        };
        buttons.Add(button1);

        if (button2Text != null)
        {
            CardAction button2 = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = button2Value,
                Type = button2ActionType,
                Title = button2Text
            };
            buttons.Add(button2);
        }

        if (cardClassName == "HeroCard")
        {
            HeroCard card = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = cardTitle,
                Subtitle = cardSubtitle,
                Images = images,
                Buttons = buttons
            };
            Attachment a = card.ToAttachment();
            msg.Attachments.Add(a);
        }
        else if (cardClassName == "ThumbnailCard")
        {
            ThumbnailCard card = new ThumbnailCard()
            {
                Title = cardTitle,
                Subtitle = cardSubtitle,
                Images = images,
                Buttons = buttons
            };
            Attachment a = card.ToAttachment();
            msg.Attachments.Add(a);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook currently does not support a bot escalating to a phone call

Answer (score 1):

Just change the type to openUrl and it will work with values of type: "tel: +xx xxx xxx xxxx"

Comment: Have you tested this on facebook messenger?

Comment: Yes, succesfully

Comment: For now it works even with Type = ActionTypes.Call and Value = "tel: +xx xxx xxx xxx" in both Facebook and Skype

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid in which version of bot framework have you tested this?

Comment: I v4 but I don't think it's relevant